# How to parse a XML file which is obtained from the URL in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to parse an XML file which I get from this [URL](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=india&hl=kn) in my program.I am following [anddev](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/parsing-xml-from-the-net-using-the-saxparser-t353.html#p1257) which is obviously a great tutorial but then,I have so many tags in my XML files.How do I parse and get the values from each of these tags? I haven't used any of the parsers till now.I need a help from SO.

Comment: You need a good [tutorial over xml](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/) and after reading this tutorial you will not see too many tags in your xml.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Vineet.Its an incredible tutorial.Thanks a lot:)